# Improving web page performance when displaying large amounts of data

Tags: sql-server

I have a ms SQL query that populates a grid view on my web page. Because the query pulls data from a linked server (oracle database) I'm finding that the performance is extremely poor.

The things I have tried so far to speed it up are;

- Only select fields that are needed.
- Getting my data from views rather than using sub queries.
- Not use any or's in where clauses.
- In my views I've used OPENQUERY(database, "sql statement") to get the data I need.

One thing that i cannot do is pull out the data from the linked server tables and store locally using a sql server job.

Is there anyway that I could possibly speed it up within my web page code behind etc?

sql is;

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
    stk_Products.stk_ItemNo AS code, com_stock.STK_PRO_CODE AS Barcode, stk_Products.stk_ItemDescription AS Description,  
    com_product.PRO_ADD_INFO_1 AS packsize, STOCK_CONTROL_FILE.OVERALL_STOCK_LEVEL, com_stock.STK_EXPIRY_DATE AS ExpiryDate,  
    com_stock.STK_PRODN_DATE AS PromoDate, com_stock.STK_QTY AS Quantity, com_stock.STK_STATUS AS Status, com_stock.STK_DATE_REC AS DateReceived,  
    com_stock.STK_LOC_ID, com_stock.STK_ZON_ID, STOCK_CONTROL_FILE.QTY_ALLOCATED, STOCK_CONTROL_FILE.AvgWkSales8,  
    stk_ProductGroupSuperReportingDivision.sup_Description 
    FROM       vw_locator_PRODUCT AS com_product INNER JOIN 
        vw_locator_STOCK AS com_stock ON 
    com_product.PRO_CODE = com_stock.STK_PRO_CODE RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    stk_Products INNER JOIN 
    stk_ProductGroup ON stk_Products.stk_ProductGroup = stk_ProductGroup.stk_ProductGroup INNER JOIN 
    stk_ProductGroupReportingDivision ON stk_ProductGroup.stk_ReportingDivision = stk_ProductGroupReportingDivision.rep_ID INNER JOIN 
    stk_ProductGroupSuperReportingDivision ON stk_ProductGroupReportingDivision.rep_SuperDivision = stk_ProductGroupSuperReportingDivision.sup_ID INNER JOIN 
    STOCK_CONTROL_FILE ON stk_Products.stk_ItemNo = STOCK_CONTROL_FILE.ITEM_NUMBER ON  
    com_stock.STK_PRO_CODE = STOCK_CONTROL_FILE.SUPPLIERS_ITEM_NUMBER COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
    WHERE        (stk_ProductGroupSuperReportingDivision.sup_Description = @division) AND (com_stock.STK_EXPIRY_DATE <= @date)
```

Comment: are you allowed to put the view on oracle?

Comment: How much data are you retrieving ? Can you paginate the results (show only some of them at one time) ? Are you sure that it's the Oracle link that's causing the problem ? If you don't query the data on Oracle and instead fill with arbitrary data, is it still slow ?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't put the view on oracle. The data set isn't massive, at most around 300 records. I've checked the query without doing the link and executes immediately - 00.00.

Comment: Without more details it is impossible to offer much advice. Those views would be worth looking at as a potential issue. Can you post the actual execution plan? Not part of the issue but you can make your life a lot easier if you start using aliases for your tables. And don't be scared to add white space to your queries so they are more legible. Those wall of text queries like this are just painful to decipher.

Comment: Back to the basic: can you share indexes on the underlying tables.